# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6.. overflowed to 0x6.. (stl_vector.h) . I know why i'm getting this but need little suggestions

Tags: c++, binary-search

In the following please look to search function. Say input vector is something perfectly fine but doesn't contain the 'target'(i.e the index of element searched by function) and somehow either my lower bound is already lowest or upper bound is already max.In this condition my ifs statement certainly underflow or overflow my vector, so i somehow want my function to return -1. I already tried to limit my ifs so that they don't add or sub to extreme index,but this lead to exceed time limit error. input: nums=[4,5,6,7,1,2] and target=3.

```
class Solution {
public:
int bs(vector<int>&nums,int l,int h){
    if(h>=l){
        int mid=l+(h-l)/2;
        if(nums[mid-1]<nums[mid]){
            if(nums[mid]>nums[mid+1]) return mid;
            else if(mid==nums.size()-2) return mid+1;
        }
        if(nums[mid]<nums[0]){
            h=mid;
            return bs(nums,l,h);
        }
       else {
            l=mid;
            return bs(nums,l,h);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    int finalMid=-1;
    int l=0;
    int h=nums.size()-1;
    if(h==finalMid) return finalMid;
    else if(h==0 && nums[0]!=target) return finalMid;
    else if(h==0 && nums[0]==target) return 0;
    int maxIndex=bs(nums,l,h);
    bool isTargetBig=target>nums[0];
    if(isTargetBig || maxIndex==h){ h=maxIndex; cout<<"hee1";}
    else {l=maxIndex; cout<<"hee2";}
    //standard binary search

    while(h>=l){
        int mid=l+(h-l)/2;
        if(nums[mid]==target) 
        {
            finalMid=mid;
            break;
        }
        if(nums[mid]<target) l=mid+1;
        if(nums[mid]>target) h=mid-1;
        else finalMid=-1;
    }
  return finalMid;  
}};
```

Comment: `nums` vector in text description is not sorted and binary search only makes sense when dealing with sorted inputs. Also, there are several implementations online if you want to learn more about binary search.

Comment: its sorted but it can also be rotated by some pivot...

Comment: There are resources online to sort a rotated sorted vector/array too. I would recommend googling the issue/query first.

Comment: i need to do it in O(logn) time complexity,sorting not an option

Comment: even if i  sort it, i have to use bsearch again. vector can be like nums=[6,13,0,4,5] . And lets say the element to be searched is 2,then the situation is same what it is right now.